# Matching and inserting records in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets of data. One sheet has Primary Id with 4 fields and other has primary Id with 2 fields.

```
          Sheet A                                         Sheet B
ID    Name    Price   Type    Category              ID      Name     Price
1                      S        Normal              2       Aus       500
2                      N        Default             1       Ind       400
```

Basically I need to match the ID of both sheets and copy the corresponding Name and Price in sheet A form Sheet B. I have tried the following code,

```
Sub Copy()

lastrowA = Worksheets("SheetA").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Set rngA = Range("A2" & lastrowA)
lastrowB = Worksheets("SheetB").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Set rngB = Range("A2" & lastrowB)
For Each x In rngB
    For Each y In rngA
        If x.Value() = y.Value Then
           ' Copy paste name and price form B to A
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why VBA? A simple [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) in Sheet A's !B2 like `=VLOOKUP($A2, 'Sheet B'!$A:$C, COLUMN(B:B), FALSE)`. Fill right one column and down as far as you like.

Comment: I am automating a task so I need to use VBA

Comment: So use `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's never a good idea to use a *reserved word* as the name of your macro. Particularly so if you plan to use a `.Copy` operation within the macro.

```
Sub MyCopy()
    Dim lastrowA As Long

    With Worksheets("SheetA")
        lastrowA = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("B2:C" & lastrowA)
            .Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, 'SheetB'!$A:$C, COLUMN(B:B), FALSE), """")"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

That bulk populates the entire region with the appropriate formula without looping then converts the returned values to raw values. Any non-matches will be blank rather than `#N/A` errors.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be done without using formulas? I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but surely you can just use either a `Vlookup` or an `Index` `Match`?

If entering the formula from VBA:

```
Cells(2,2).FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Sheet2!R2C2:R3C3,MATCH(RC[-1],Sheet2!RC[-1]:R[1]C[-1],0),1)"
Cells(2,3).FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Sheet2!R2C2:R3C3,MATCH(RC[-2],Sheet2!R2C1:R3C1,0),2)"
```

Then you can find the last row in the ID column on sheet 1, and fill the formula down both of the columns. Once the formula has been filled down, just copy and paste as values.

```
Dim lstRow As Long
lstRow = Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '' find last row
Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lstRow, 3)).FillDown
Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lstRow, 3)).Copy
Cells(2, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Edit: You can use the `lstRow` variable within the VBA formula to make sure the formula is covering the whole range everytime the automation is run. You can use the 'Record Macro' button within excel to get the code for a formula, if you are not comfortable creating them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with your code is that

```
Set rngA = Range("A2" & lastrowA)
```

evaluates to Range("A25") for lastRowA=5.
If you want to address multiple cells, use

```
Set rngA = Range("A2:A" & lastrowA)
```

to get Range("A2:A5") for lastRowA = 5.

Besides that, formulas as already mentioned are an elegant solution as well.